# Travis CI doesn't deploy to Azure from GitHub the war file correctly

Tags: java, maven, azure, travis-ci, azure-webapps

My problem is that the packaged `war` file is not deployed from GitHub to Azure using Travis-CI correctly - the entire repository with the generated files are just copy-pasted. Here is what I do:

**My approach:**

I follow the Travis tutorial about [Azure web app deployment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/azure-web-apps/) and try to achieve the same in the minimal form. My goal is to assemble a `war` file and deploy it to Azure web app with Tomcat 8.0 container.

My project has the following `.travis.yml` configuration (I have omitted Java-8 definition, Sonar add-ons, and Coveralls after_success script for the sake of brevity):

```
script:
   - mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package sonar:sonar

deploy:
   provider: azure_web_apps
   skip_cleanup: true
```

I use `AZURE_WA_USERNAME`, `AZURE_WA_PASSWORD` and `AZURE_WA_SITE` environment variables.

I follow the standard Maven directory structure. The output directory is the standard `/target`. Thus, on the Travis is generated into:

```
/home/travis/build/MY_USERNAME/MY_WEBAPP/target/MY_WEBAPP.war
```

Where `MY_USERNAME` is the GitHub login name and `MY_WEBAPP` is the name of my application. The deployment looks fine at the first sight (I skipped similar lines):

```
Deploying application
[detached HEAD 9fd0ce7] Skip Cleanup Commit
54 files changed, 128 insertions(+)
create mode 100644 target/MY_WEBAPP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
create mode 100644 target/MY_WEBAPP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war.original
create mode 100644 target/MY_WEBAPP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/classes/... <- Skipped 3 lines
create mode 100644 target/MY_WEBAPP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/...     <- Skipped 20+ lines
... irrelevant ...                                                     <- Skipped 7 lines
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

**What is wrong and how it should be correct:**

If I upload manually the `war` file via FTP(S) to the Azure directory `/site/wwwroot/webapps`, it's unpacked and deployed within a minute and works well.

Unlike the manual copy, Travis takes all the content and copy-paste it literally into the Azure webapp resulting in the mess like:

[image: Azure directory structure]

The `war` file hasn't been uploaded into the `webapps` folder. The newly created Azure webapp contains `site/wwwroot/webapps/ROOT` folder and is needed to upload the `war` file on the `ROOT` folder level. I have expected Travis would perform "smarter" behavior.

**Question:**

How to deploy to Azure from GitHub using Travis-CI correctly? I bet I miss something that isn't documented.

---

**My workaround-attempts:**

I have tried to fix the thing in several ways (none of them has worked). I consider all of them dirty:

1. I tried to specify what to deploy in `.travis.yml` (no effect, everything is copied still):

   ```
   file_glob: true
   file: "/home/travis/build/MY_USERNAME/MY_WEBAPP/target/MY_WEBAPP*.war"
   ```
2. An ugly bruteforce: Change the output directory from `/target` to `/webapp` resultin to override the destination folder in Azure upon deployment in the `<build>` section of 'pom.xml`:

   ```
   <directory>/webapps</directory>
   ...
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <warName>MY_WEBAPP</warName>
           <outputDirectory>/webapps</outputDirectory>
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
3. Rename the output folder to `webapps` in `.travis.yml`:

   ```
   after_success:
    - bash mv /home/travis/build/MY_USERNAME/MY_WEBAPP/target/ /home/travis/build/MY_USERNAME/MY_WEBAPP/webapps/
   ```

   > /bin/mv: /bin/mv: cannot execute binary file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue with uploading deployment scripts:

**.deployment**

```
[config]
command=deployment.cmd
```

**deployment.cmd**

```
@echo off
echo Azure: Deploying site

echo Azure: Removing the current war file
del %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\webapps\MY_WEBAPP.war /S /Q

echo Azure: Removing the current webapp folder
rmdir %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\webapps\MY_WEBAPP /S /Q

echo Azure: Copying war to the webapps folder
xcopy %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\..\repository\target\MY_WEBAPP.war %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\webapps /Y /s
```